# MySQL ordering by distinct count

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a select query which produces the following:

```
select customers.city , books.title                                                                   
from loaned, books, customers                                                                         
where loaned.userID = customers.userID                                                                
and loaned.bookID = books.bookID 
+------------+-------------------------------+
| city       | title                         |
+------------+-------------------------------+
| Harrogate  | The cross rabbit              |
| Harrogate  | PHP and MySQL web development |
| Harrogate  | PHP and MySQL web development |
| Whitehaven | Greek Mythology               |
| Whitehaven | Dino-soaring                  |
| Whitehaven | Dino-soaring                  |
| Sale       | Magic tricks                  |
| Sale       | Magic tricks                  |
| Sale       | Magic tricks                  |
| Sale       | Dino-soaring                  |
| Sale       | Dino-soaring                  |
+------------+-------------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to find the most popular title for each city and so I did the following:

```
group by city
order by count(distinct title) desc
```

however this doesn't produce the correct results. I get:

```
+------------+-------------------------------+
| city       | title                         |
+------------+-------------------------------+
| Sale       | Dino-soaring                  |
| Whitehaven | Dino-soaring                  |
| Harrogate  | PHP and MySQL web development |
+------------+-------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This appears to be sorted alphabetically, not by popularity. 
Having got the data I thought it would be easy to order it to how I require but it's not turned out that way.
Do I need to do some sort of join or something more complicated than that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who answered. As this was a question for a test I didn't want to 'cut and paste' someone else's work but used their logic to make my own query. Here's what I got:

```
select city, title
from (
    select customers.city as city, books.title as title, count(books.title) as cnt
    from books, customers, loaned
    where loaned.userID = customers.userID
    and loaned.bookID = books.bookID
    group by title, city
    order by cnt desc) as tbl
group by city
```

Results:

```
+------------+-------------------------------+
| city       | title                         |
+------------+-------------------------------+
| Harrogate  | PHP and MySQL web development |
| Sale       | Magic tricks                  |
| Whitehaven | Dino-soaring                  |
+------------+-------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `distinct title` with just `title` and this should solve your issue..

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this problem in 3 steps. First get the count of each book from each city.

```
select customers.city, books.title, count(books.title) as count
from loaned, books, customers
where loaned.userID = customers.userID
and loaned.bookID = books.bookID
group by customers.city, books.title
```

This query will return the following rows.

```
+------------+-------------------------------+-------+
| city       | title                         | count |
+------------+-------------------------------+-------+
| Harrogate  | The cross rabbit              | 1     |
| Harrogate  | PHP and MySQL web development | 2     |
| Whitehaven | Greek Mythology               | 1     |
| Whitehaven | Dino-soaring                  | 2     |
| Sale       | Magic tricks                  | 3     |
| Sale       | Dino-soaring                  | 2     |
+------------+-------------------------------+-------+
```

Using that data, then I'll use that to do a group by on each city with the most count.

```
select city, max(count) as count
from 
(
  select customers.city , books.title, count(books.title) as count
  from loaned, books, customers
  where loaned.userID = customers.userID
  and loaned.bookID = books.bookID
  group by customers.city, books.title
) as city_book_max_count
group by city
```

Which will return these rows,

```
+------------+-------+
| city       | count |
+------------+-------+
| Harrogate  | 2     |
| Whitehaven | 2     |
| Sale       | 3     |
+------------+-------+
```

Using the data from the 2 tables, we can then join them on city and the count, to get the corresponding books that match on both tables.

```
select city_book_count.city, city_book_count.title
from 
(
  select customers.city , books.title, count(books.title) as count
  from loaned, books, customers
  where loaned.userID = customers.userID
  and loaned.bookID = books.bookID
  group by customers.city, books.title
) as city_book_count
join
(
  select city, max(count) as count
  from 
  (
    select customers.city , books.title, count(books.title) as count
    from loaned, books, customers
    where loaned.userID = customers.userID
    and loaned.bookID = books.bookID
    group by customers.city, books.title
  ) as city_book_count_temp
  group by city
) as city_book_max_count
on city_book_count.city = city_book_max_count.city
  and city_book_count.count = city_book_max_count.count
```

Answer (score 0):

I am removing customer table, as there is no output from this table

```
select customers.city , books.title , count(books.title) Total                       
from loaned, books, customers                                                                         
where loaned.userID = customers.userID                                                       
and loaned.bookID = books.bookID 
    group by customers.city , books.title order by 3 desc
```

Comment: Yes there is, it's where I get the customers city from. This is not stored in the loaned or books table.

Comment: Thanks thank works but it now has a third column (with number of titles) and also shows how many of every other title there is. Is there any way just to show the most popular book for each city?